# How to filter list based on two arguments for lambda function without hardcoding the param?

Tags: python-3.x

```
records=[["chi",20.0], ["beta", 50.0],["ama",20.0], ["alpha",50.0]]
f2 = lambda l: l[1] 
marks = list(map(f2,records))
marks = list(set(marks))

def second_largest(l):
    l.sort()
    if len(l)==1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return l[len(l)-2]
mark = second_largest(marks)
```

Expected output :
['ama',chi']

Is it possible to filter the records by the 'mark' which I have obtained above with filter function?
The above problem can be solved by nested for loop I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: `f2 = lambda l: l[1] ` is equivalent to `def f2(l): return l[1]`, which is preferred. Your question is not clear. Please provide expected output.

Comment: @DYZ updated output. From the list I want the name of the record in sorted order with second largest total

Comment: The question is not getting any clearer. WHY is that output expected?

Comment: records contains data with each student name and marks obtained (eg ["Ga",100]). I want the name of the students from the records who has obtained marks which is second largest in the given data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### normal solution:

1. bulid a list without duplicate float value
2. sort it,find the second large value
3. bulid a result list,which elements equal to second large value

#### code:

```
records=[["chi",20.0], ["beta", 50.0],["ama",20.0], ["alpha",50.0]]
records_set = list(set([record[1] for record in records]))
second_large_value = sorted(records_set)[-2 if len(records_set)>1 else 0]
print([record[0] for record in records if record[1] == second_large_value])
```

#### result:

```
['chi', 'ama']
```

### fancy one-liner solution

- Since your solution already worked, I provide a funcy one-liner solution.If you only use this code once, never maintain/read it, you can use this

#### code:

```
records=[["chi",20.0], ["beta", 50.0],["ama",20.0], ["alpha",50.0]]
print([record[0] for record in records if record[1] == sorted(list(set([record[1] for record in records])))[-2 if len(set([record[1] for record in records]))>=2 else 0]])
```

#### result:

```
['chi', 'ama']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
records=[["chi",20.0], ["beta", 50.0],["ama",20.0], ["alpha",50.0]]
f2 = lambda l: l[1] 
marks = list(map(f2,records))
marks = list(set(marks))

def second_largest(l):
    l.sort()
    if len(l)==1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return l[len(l)-2]
mark = second_largest(marks)
fun = lambda l : l[1] == mark
records = list(filter(fun,records))
list(map(lambda l:l[0],records))
```

Input : records=[["chi",20.0], ["beta", 50.0],["ama",20.0], ["alpha",50.0]]
Output : ['ama', 'chi']

This worked for me